# Own plugin displays inconsistently on single WordPress version

Tags: css, wordpress

I have been developing a simple WordPress Plugin that displays a simple message pertaining to the use of cookies on the site.

It has been deployed on my company's various WordPress sites and HTML sites. However, there has been some big differences in how the plugin is displayed.

[image: http://img526.imageshack.us/img526/4240/dfdsfasfda.png]

This is how the message is displayed on the main WordPress Site. This is also how it looks when running on their HTML site

However, on another WordPress site it appears like so:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img209/5092/20130612103958.png]

The image is squashed against the site and it takes up the left hand side of the website.

Both WordPress sites use the same version of WordPress (3.3.1) and there is no change in how they are displayed in a variety of browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox).

Why is the same plugin being displayed so differently across the same versions of WordPress?

**style.css**

```
.popup-box {    
    position: fixed;
    left:50%;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding:10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 5);
    z-index:10000;

}

.popup-box .popup-inner {
    float:left;
}
```

**Popup.php** - Set properties based upon admins choice.

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .popup-box {
        width:<?php if(get_option('width') != ''){ echo get_option('width');}else{ echo '200';}?>px;
        background-colour:<?php if(get_option('bgcolour') != ''){ echo get_option('bgcolour');}else{ echo '#000000';} ?>;
        color:<?php if(get_option('fontcolour') != ''){ echo get_option('fontcolour');}else{ echo '#FFFFFF';} ?>;
        font-size:<?php if(get_option('fontsize') != ''){ echo get_option('fontsize'); } else{ echo '13px';} ?>px;
        margin-left:<?php if (get_option('width') !=''){echo 0 - (get_option('width')/2);} else {echo '-100';}?>px;
        <?php if(get_option('position') != ''){ echo get_option('position');}else{ echo 'bottom';} ?>:0px;

    }

    .popup-box .popup-inner {
        width:<?php echo get_option('width'); ?>px;
        line-height:<?php echo (get_option(fontsize')+ 6); ?>px;
    }
    </style>
```

**Popup.php** - Display Popup

```
    if(get_option('display') == 'yes'){
    ?>

<body onload="check()">

<div class="popup-box" id="x">
    <div class="sticky-inner"><?php echo stripslashes(get_option('popup_message')); ?></div>
    <input id="btnAgree" type="button" value ="I agree" onclick="save()"/>
    <input id="btnDisagree" type="button" value ="I disagree" onclick="hide()"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have conflicting CSS rules or JavaScript errors on the sites the plugin doesn't render as you want it to. Use Firebug and check the console/ styles panel for errors.

Comment: Hi,
It actually turned out that the link to the styles folder was not assigned correctly. 
Thanks, however, for your answer and suggestion to check in Firebug (although I'm not quite why I didn't spot it before) 
thanks...